# Take Her By The Arm To Some Place

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the usage of "*take*".  In this dictionary, [definition 1](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take_1#take_1__1) for "*take*" reads:

> to move something or someone from one place to another

In the same entry, [definition 7](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take_1#take_1__13) for "*take*" reads:

> to reach out and get something, especially with your hand

Then, on google, there is this [sentence](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/in-supreme-court/1200676.html):

> He then led the victim out the back door of the apartment, telling her not to tell anyone what had happened.   Finally, ***he took her by the arm to a nearby wooded area***.   When she screamed Carter killed her.

The usage in the example seems to compress the two senses of "*take*" into a single phrase.  Could it be nonstandard?

Comment: Nope.  It's fine.

Comment: It really is all definition 1, coupled with [definition 12 of ***by***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/by): *used for saying which part of a person’s body or thing you take in your hand when you hold them*  Definition 7 of *take* is in the context of taking cookies off a tray, etc.

Comment: @Jim  In "*he took her by the arm into a nearby wooded area*," the phrase "*by the arm*" does not modify the noun "*her*". It modifies the verb "*took*".

Comment: @meatie- Very good.  But what's your point?

Answer (score 1):

He took her by the hand to a nearby wooden area.

The sentence is absolutely standard.  The phrase "by the hand" in the sentence means "holding her hand". It's the same as you say "They were walking hand in hand (holding each other's hand). Another example: He shook her by the hand.

Comment: In "*he took her by the arm into a nearby wooded area*," the phrase "*by the arm*" does not modify the noun "*her*". It modifies the verb "*took*".

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the base of the sentence is *took her to a nearby wooded area*, and *by the arm* was added as a specification.

*By the arm* also could have easily been replaced, as well, in hypothetical situations.

> He took her unconscious to a nearby wooded area.
>
> He took her kicking and screaming to a nearby wooded area.
>
> He took her in handcuffs to a nearby wooded area.

Two of the variants are adjectives, which only modify the subject. *By the arm* is thus independent of the verb.

Although in this case, placing *by the arm* in front sounds somewhat awkward to me, since it places the emphasis on the detail rather than the story, the usage is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: In "*he took her by the arm into a nearby wooded area*," the phrase "*by the arm*" does not modify the noun "*her*". It modifies the verb "*took*".